# Enviando localização para webservice

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geolocalização

Olá, eu estou com um problema, eu tenho um **service** no android que captura a localização do usuário em um determinado intervalo.

Capturado eu envio para o servidor, onde ele vai pegar essa localização e salvar no database.

O problema é que talves o usuário nem sempre tem internet para enviar a localização, então eu preciso salvar essa localização, para quando a conexão estiver disponível eu enviar a localização para o `webservice`.

Eu pesquisei mas encontrei poucas explicações para este problema.

Atualmente eu estou tentando usar `SharePreferences` para salvar essa localização e estou criando filas para requisição, pois o usuário pode ficar 3 dias por exemplo sem conexão, então a quantidade de dados salvos seria grande(Então eu envio por partes) e ultrapassaria o limit do post, get ou header para fazer o request.

Enfim, eu queria saber se existe alguma lib que cuida desse problema, criar uma fila de requisições e que se cair a conexão com a internet, então espera, e quando disponível refazer a requisição.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu pessoalmente faço como você. Criei uma classe que monta a fila de envios pro servidor, quando adiciono um request ao fim da fila tento enviar os requests se houver conexão. Também tenho um service que é chamado quando a conexão é alterada e se houver conexão tenta rodar a fila. Essa solução vem funcionando muito bem.

Na documentação do Google eles recomendam o uso de Sync Adapters. Quando criei essa parte no meu aplicativo não tinha conhecimento dessa recomendação, se tivesse possivelmente tentaria implementar desse jeito. Infelizmente está em inglês e é extensa e abrangente demais pra resumir em uma mensagem aqui. Você pode encontrar o que precisa pra utilizar um SyncAdapter aqui:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/sync-adapters/index.html

**CÓDIGO SOLICITADO PELO AUTOR DA PERGUNTA**

Primeira coisa importante na classe é ser um Singleton que eu inicio na OnCreate da Application, assim todo o programa vai ter sempre a mesma instância da fila.

Eu crio meus parâmetros do request como JSONObject, adiciono eles a uma JSONArray com todos os requests e salvo a array como texto nas SharedPreferences mesmo. Escolhi fazer desse jeito pois é muito fácil transformar JSON pra texto e vice versa:

```
public void addToRequestQueue( final JSONObject request )
{
    try
    {
        String pendingRequests = mPref.getString( Globals.PENDING_REQUESTS, "[]" );

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray( pendingRequests );
        jArray.put( request );

        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit( );
        mEditor.putString( Globals.PENDING_REQUESTS, jArray.toString( ) );
        mEditor.apply( );
    }
    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }

    runQueue( );
}
```

Depois disso tenho o método runQueue que roda a fila de requests. Como eu disse meu programa tem requests que precisam ser sequenciais, em algumas ocasiões tenho uma fila com 2 requests, no primeiro o servidor retorna informações essenciais pro segundo request. Logo em caso de não haver conexão, eu não vou ter essas informações retornadas pelo servidor. Pra fazer o segundo request preciso ter certeza que o primeiro request já obteve sua resposta. Então tive que criar um semáforo que só permite a runQueue rodar caso não esteja esperando nenhuma resposta do servidor.

```
public void runQueue( )
{
    try
    {
        if( semaphore )
        {
            return;
        }

        semaphore = true;
        int position = 0;

        String pendingRequests = mPref.getString( Globals.PENDING_REQUESTS, "[]" );
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray( pendingRequests );

        if( array.length( ) > position )
        {
            JSONObject request = array.getJSONObject( position );
            String tag = request.getString( "tag" );

            switch( tag )
            {
                case Globals.MONITOR:
                {
                    // Se necessário adicionar informações novas ao JSONObject request
                    sendRequest( position, tag, request );
                    break;
                }
                .
                .
                .
                default:
                    semaphore = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            semaphore = false;
        }
    }
    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        semaphore = false;
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

Utilizo Volley pra me comunicar com o servidor, mas como preciso esperar a resposta do servidor, precisei usar um RequestFuture que bloqueia o Thread, logo não podemos usar o UI Thread pra não travar o aplicativo:

```
public void sendRequest( final int position, final String tag, final JSONObject params )
{
    Thread thread = new Thread( )
    {
        @Override
        public void run( )
        {
            JSONObject result = syncVolleyRequest( tag, params );
            if( result != null )
            {
                parseRequestResult( position, tag, result );
            }
            else
            {
                semaphore = false;
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start( );
}

public JSONObject syncVolleyRequest( final String tag, final JSONObject params )
{
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector( mContext );
    if( cd.hasActiveInternetConnection( ) )
    {
        RequestFuture< String > futureRequest = RequestFuture.newFuture( );
        StringRequest request =
                new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, NetworkConfig.SERVER_URL, futureRequest,
                        futureRequest )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map< String, String > getParams( )
                    {
                        return getRequestParams( params );
                    }
                };
        request.setTag( tag );

        mRequestQueue = VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance( mContext ).getVolleyRequestQueue( );
        mRequestQueue.add( request );

        try
        {
            return new JSONObject( futureRequest.get( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) );
        }
        catch( JSONException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );

        }
        catch( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
            Thread.currentThread( ).interrupt( );
        }
        catch( ExecutionException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        catch( TimeoutException e )
        {
            semaphore = false;
            runQueue( );
            e.printStackTrace( );
            return null;
        }
    }

    semaphore = false;
    return null;
}
```

Depois que recebo a resposta dou parse no resultado, se obtiver sucesso apago o Request da fila a e rodo ela de novo:

```
private void parseRequestResult( final int position, final String tag, final JSONObject result )
{
    try
    {
        if( ! result.getBoolean( "error" ) )
        {
            switch( tag )
            {
                case Globals.MONITOR:
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    break;
                .
                .
                .
                default:
                    break;
            }

            semaphore = false;

            deleteRequest( position );
            runQueue( );
        }
    }
    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }

    semaphore = false;
}



private void deleteRequest( int position )
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray pivotArray = new JSONArray( );

        String pendingRequests = mPref.getString( Globals.PENDING_REQUESTS, "[]" );
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray( pendingRequests );

        for( int i = 0; i < array.length( ); i++ )
        {
            if( i != position )
            {
                pivotArray.put( array.getJSONObject( i ) );
            }
        }

        array = pivotArray;

        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit( );
        mEditor.putString( Globals.PENDING_REQUESTS, array.toString( ) );
        mEditor.apply( );
    }
    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

Como você só vai enviar localização, não acho que precise ser sequencial, logo não precisaria usar o RequestFuture nem o semáforo (que é uma parte do código que achei bem confusa e suscetível a erros, toda possibilidade de falha nesse código eu tenho que botar semaphore = false, se esquecer a fila é interrompida e só vai rodar quando for chamada novamente. Pretendo rever futuramente).

Comment: Então, eu tenho um SyncAdapter rodando... Ele é quem envia os dados pro servidor. Então vou seguir com essa ideia mesmo, com certeza deve funcionar bem. Eu uso o SyncAdapter pra enviar os dados pro servidor, ou seja, eu tenho 3 services, um para pegar a localização outro pra executar o SyncAdapter e o outro é para a conta de autenticação. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Você consegue me mostrar um pouco do seu código que você fez sua fila? Obrigado.

Comment: Adicionei as partes importantes do meu código explicadas na resposta.

Comment: Valeu! Muito obrigado. Sua ideia é praticamente a mesma que a minha. Muito obrigado por compartilhar. :)